# ListView in Fragment does not work

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

My `MainActivity` is a `TabbedActivity` with two tabs, each represented by an individual `Fragment`. The second Tab should show a `ListView`. Within my MainActivity I use this `Adapter` to apply my Fragments:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super (fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment =null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, Fragment2.class.getName());
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, Fragment2.class.getName());
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Tab1";
            case 1:
                return "Tab2";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is the `Fragment2 class`:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
protected List<Transaction> myTransactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
private Context mContext;
DatabaseHelper DBH = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
String DepositInputValue, DepositInputDate, DepositInputNote;

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public AssetsOverviewList() {
}

public static Fragment2 newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Cursor res = DBH.getAllData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        //do something
        return;
    }
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        buffer.append("Value :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
        buffer.append("Date  :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
        buffer.append("Note  :" + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
    }
    // Show all data
    showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());

    while (res.moveToNext()) {


        DepositInputValue = res.getString(1);
        DepositInputDate = res.getString(2);
        DepositInputNote = res.getString(3);
    }
}

private class LastTransactionsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaction> {
    public LastTransactionsListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.transaction_list_view, myTransactions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_view, parent, false);
        }
        Transaction currentTransaction = myTransactions.get(position);
        return itemView;
    }
}
private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Transaction> adapter = new LastTransactionsListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) list.findViewById(last_transactions_listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

I get an error at the `LastTransactionsListAdapter` right after the `super` where it says 'MainActivity is not an enclosing class'. Six lines beneath it tells me that `getLayoutInflater` cannot be applied. If I delete all the `ListView` related stuff the app works just fine. How do I solve this?

Comment: Your code has no sense. `ArrayAdapter` should description single row, but you are trying to deal whole `ListView` inside. `ListView` its list of multiple rows, make something like this [link](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity/)

Comment: @grabarz121 I will take a look at that soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of your line -

```
super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.transaction_list_view, myTransactions);
```

Here to get context, you have done MainActivity.this but this is not your MainActivity class but instead your Fragment class.

To get context in a Fragment, you can call its calling activity class using `getActivity()` method. So change this to to -

```
super(getActivity(), R.layout.transaction_list_view, myTransactions);
```

same is the case with your `getLayoutInflater()` call. This method is only available for activities and not fragments so for that as well you need to do the same thing. Call it using `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`

So your Line becomes -

```
itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_view, parent, false);
```

Comment: thank you. I am somewhat new to android / java programming so I did not know that...

Answer (score 1):

Try using below Adapter

```
private class LastTransactionsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaction> {
        public LastTransactionsListAdapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.transaction_list_view, myTransactions);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_view, parent, false);
            }
            Transaction currentTransaction = myTransactions.get(position);
            return itemView;
        }
    }
```